# What was Jabba's status among other Hutts?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jabba-the-hutt

So we know that Jabba the Hutt was leader of a vast criminal empire. In fact, according to Legends canon, Jabba's organization was apparently the Outer Rim equivalent of Black Sun, or nearly so. He was certainly powerful enough that Black Sun's leader, Prince Xizor, considered Jabba to be one of the only two individuals that posed a threat to his position (the other being Darth Vader). We also know that Hutts in general respect wealth & power, with such things determining a Hutt's status within the social ranks of Hutt society.

What we don't know, however, was where Jabba fit within Hutt society. Given his wealth, power, and influence, you'd think Jabba would be fairly high up the social ladder. However, Jabba resides on Tatooine, which is quite some distance from Nal Hutta (the Hutt homeworld), and does not appear to be one of the ruling Hutts in their society. In fact, the only Hutts we see Jabba interacting with are Durga - the other Hutt on Tatooine - and Jabba's uncle/aunt on Coruscant. In both cases, the other Hutts defer to Jabba. However, in both cases, the other Hutt falls within Jabba's personal sphere of influence.

**What exactly is Jabba's position/rank within Hutt society, and is he considered any kind of leader or official figure to the other Hutts?**

Comment: IIRC, he was a member of the council of Hutts, making him one of the highest ranked of the species.

Comment: @RogueJedi - interesting. If you can find something to support that, it'd make a great answer

Comment: Didn't other Hutts consider him a bit of a perv because of his fondness for humanoid slave girls?

Comment: I find it hard to imagine a Hutt on a ladder.

Comment: Jabba was _the_ Hutt.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Canon:**

During the Clone Wars, Jabba was the leader of the "[Grand Hutt Council](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grand_Hutt_Council)." The Council ruled the entire Hutt Clan and the Hutt Cartel.

[image: Hutt Council: Five Hutt, two apparently present as holograms, sit in an arc behind a raised desk-like structure, facing three humanoids standing below and before them. The centre of the dark room is illuminated from above, focusing the eye on the humanoids. The rest of the room is dark with 3 braziers burning in the background to right, left and centre.]

**Legends:**

Jabba was also the leader of the Council in the Legends continuity.

Additionally, he was the leader of the [Desilijic](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Desilijic) clan, one of the most powerful Hutt Kajidics.

So Jabba was in fact a very highly ranked Hutt.

Comment: He was also the son of a very influential Hutt, mentioned in the Clone Wars series... can you remember which Hutt that was? He contracted the Jedi to save baby Jabba from ?Assaj? Or was it Jabba's son that needed saving... guess I need to re-watch the series :-)

Comment: @TylerH Jabba was an adult during the Clone Wars.He had the Jedi find his son, Rotta.